# Custom Category fields duplicated

Tags: category, magento2.4.5

We had an issue where updates to a custom **category_form.xml** file were made that changed their placement on the page. When I reverted back to the way it should have been, I now get duplicated fields.

This happened when we upgraded from 2.4.1 to 2.4.5.

[image]

The promo fields are also getting duplicated, but I'm guessing whatever the issue is with the author fields will be the same.

/app/code/Vendor/CategoryAuthorProfile/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd"> 
<fieldset name="product_listing_page">
<settings>
    <label translate="true">Product Listing Page (PLP) Setup</label>
    <collapsible>true</collapsible>
</settings>
<fieldset name="author_profile">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Author Profile</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="is_profile_displayed">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do you want to display the author profile?</item>
                <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                </item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">The Author Profile will display in the first two spots of the product grid.</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    *additional fields removed for brevity
</fieldset>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**UPDATE**

It looks like the issue may be with trying to embed a fieldset inside of a fieldset. If I remove the embedded fieldset, it works just fine.

/app/code/Vendor/CategoryAuthorProfile/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd"> 
<fieldset name="product_listing_page">
<settings>
    <label translate="true">Product Listing Page (PLP) Setup</label>
    <collapsible>true</collapsible>
</settings>
    <field name="is_profile_displayed">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do you want to display the author profile?</item>
                <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                </item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">The Author Profile will display in the first two spots of the product grid.</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    *additional fields removed for brevity
</fieldset>
</form>
```

[image]

I tried setting the additional fieldset using settings instead of an argument, but that also did not work.

```
<fieldset name="product_listing_page">
  <settings>
      <label translate="true">Product Listing Page (PLP) Setup</label>
      <collapsible>true</collapsible>
  </settings>
  <fieldset name="author_profile">
    <settings>
      <label translate="true">Author Profile</label>
      <collapsible>true</collapsible>
    </settings>
```

**Question: How then can I embed a fieldset inside of a fieldset in M2.4.5?**